# Use directories in url as php variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am after a way of using the directories in the URL as PHP variables. Similar to Wordpress (if not all blogging platforms) I want a way to, say, pass domain.com/directory into a php file.

The reason for this is so that when I create my own blog things, the URLs will be SEO friendly.

Forexample, instead of

```
domain.com/?blog=1&foo=1&bar=1&foobar=5
```

I want

```
domain.com/1/1/1/5 or something
```

where I can then use the explode function to get variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that functionality in php, you need `mod_rewrite` or the equivalent in your webserver of choice, and to rewrite the url path into a get param instead.

Google "clean urls drupal", for an example of it in the wild.

Answer (score 4):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /?blog=$1&foo=$2&bar=$3&foobar=$4 [L]
```

There's a lot of generators on google, search it and stackoverflow about rewrite rules, you'll find a lot of info.

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [L]
```

then in your index.php you can do explode, regular expresions or whatewer you want with `$_GET['url']`

or you can skip files that alredy exists like css or javascript and image files

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)$ ?blog=$1&foo=$2&bar=$3&foobar=$4 [PT,L]
```

I think this ought to work for your case specifically. The (.*) groups one or more characters of any type separated by a /. In this case you'll get them as GETs with the keys e.g foo

Otherwise as a string for exploding:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ blog.php?string=$1 [PT,L]
```

Assuming there's a blog.php file in the same directory to process the string
Hope it helps